# Moving from QGLWidget to QWindow

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4, qt5

I have some code using Qt 4. I want to migrate it to Qt 5 and switch to QOpenGL stuff. I can't understand where the code from `void paintGL()` and `void initializeGL()` needs to go in a QWindow. Can anyone help me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple example of using QWindow with OpenGL.

To simplify OpenGL development I have created an abstract class GLWindow, which contains the virtual functions `initializeGL()`, `paintGL()` and `resizeGL(int w, int h)`. I believe the source code shows the relationship between the old style and the new style.

The example is available here:

https://github.com/mortennobel/QtOpenGLChapter/tree/master/OpenGL3xAlt

Answer (score 0):

Qt has [at least one example (Overpainting)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/overpainting.html) of putting widgets over an OpenGL scene.  By looking at that, it appears the easiest way would be to inherit from `QGLWidget` instead of `QWidget` and override the appropriate virtual functions for initialize and paint.

Answer (score 0):

The standard example for using QWindow with OpenGL is [hellowindow](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/examples/opengl/hellowindow/hellowindow.cpp.html) in qtbase/examples/opengl.

There is no direct replacement for initializeGL and paintGL. Instead you do something like this:

- Have a QWindow with surface type OpenGLSurface.
- Create a QOpenGLContext with a matching format.
- When the window receives an expose event, start rendering (makeCurrent, your GL calls and finally swapBuffers).